# wso2 esb cache mediator performance

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We are planning to use cache mediator in wso2 esb for caching the responses , the esb servers will be clustered.

Are there any performance related issues with Cache mediator ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no known performance issues in using cache mediator.

But please note that you have to use ESB version 4.9.0 or above to support distributed caching. Its better if you can build the latest product from the source since there are some [bug fixes](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4879) done to the cache mediator later. You can use [this](https://wso2.github.io/using-maven.html) guide to build it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: we had downloaded the 4.9.0 from the WSO2 site and are developing the solution , hope it will be fine.